# Cisco IPSec forgets password (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, password, vpn, keychain

Cisco IPSec seems to have no way to store the password of the connection permanently. I have found on the web some solutions for the Mountain Lion release, but none for OS-X Mavericks.

Is it impossible, or has someone found an answer and didn't post it?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198817/how-do-you-get-a-cisco-vpn-connection-to-remember-its-password), it's not so much a problem with the OS as a problem with the configuration of the VPN on the *server* side.

One of the options your IT admins can do is force passwords to not be remembered for the VPN connection, and the OS X client will honor this setting. If you have the keychain open and are looking at the saved password when you connect, you can actually see the saved password **disappear** when you connect to the server.

I've searched for a way around this [going so far as trying to applescript the login window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207161/how-do-i-connect-a-vpn-connection-using-applescript), but they've blocked that avenue is well.