# How do you get a Cisco VPN connection to remember its password?

Tags: macos, network, password, keychain, vpn

## The Problem

I've got a Cisco IPSEC VPN connection in my network settings on a Yosemite machine. It works fine, aside from prompting for a password on every single connection. The saved password is ignored entirely.

## Background

If I enter the password under the network settings and click connect, the saved password vanishes, and the dialog prompting for a password appears. I've verified that the password is correct (it's copy-pasted from a document).

## Things that didn't work

- [A suggested solution](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009082703155512) to this for Snow Leopard was to save the password, open Keychain Access, locate the "Xauth" key in the system keychain, and grant `/usr/libexec/configd` access to the key. This had no effect.
- Usual permissions repair/disk check stuff

## Weird stuff

If I watch keychain access while hitting the connect button, the saved password **vanishes outright** from the keychain right when the dialog appears.

## Overall Question

How do I get the password correctly saved so I don't have to rekey it on every connection?

Comment: hmm. I also get weird authentication issues on Yosemite especially in the Network dialogue. Wouldn't be surprised if there is a bug involved.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't depends on remote VPN policies (now allowing password saving)?

Comment: That.. would explain why it straight-up disappears from the keychain if explicitly saved. Will have to have a chat with the network admins!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both answers here as I write this have the right of it, but the existence of the `vpn` command line means that we can get around this user-hostile design with `expect`. Thanks go to the previous answerers, GhostLyrics for revealing the existence of the server side option that turns off password saving, and Hans for revealing the `vpn` command line client.

Create a file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout 10
set addr ""  # VPN Host
set user ""  # Username
set pass ""  # Password (ensure that special characters are escaped)
set group "" # Group NUMBER shown in connect prompt


spawn /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect $addr
expect "\r\nGroup:*"
send -- "$group\r"
expect "\r\nUsername:*"
send -- "$user\r"
expect "Password: "
send -- "$pass\r"
expect eof
```

Fill out the `set` fields as normal. If your VPN is like mine, you're given a list of "groups" when you run the `vpn connect`. Run this once by hand, and note which number corresponds to the group you want to connect with. It won't change between runs unless the admins add/remove groups. You can't use the name here, the program expects a number.

Once everything is filled in, `chmod +x` this script and run it. I am now able to connect to my VPN, hands free!

Comment: at the end, here is a bonus, open the stupid client itself and watch yourself already connected! After `expect eof` do `spawn /usr/bin/open "/Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Secure\ Mobility\ Client.app"`

Answer (score 18):

I guess you are using anyconnect to connect to the Cisco VPN server. AnyConnect can also be used from Terminal. This works on macOS Sierra and AnyConnect 3.1.14018. Create a bash script with the following command:

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect your-vpn.server.here -s <.credentials
```

And put the login details in the file .credentials with the following three lines:

```
0
your-username
your-password
```

Don't forget to put reasonable permissions on the files.

Comment: User states "I've got a Cisco IPSEC VPN connection in my network settings on a Yosemite machine". This choice of words led me to conclude with rather high certainty that they are using the build-in VPN solution inside System Preferences/Network/+

Comment: can you pass that file through somehow with the usernames &/or passwords encrypted? like with the passwords file on linux

Answer (score 10):

From reading your question I get the impression that you're doing everything correctly and the Cisco VPN Server has the option to allow saving of passwords client-side set to `disallow`.

I know for certain that such a setting exists.

Comment: It's still annoying that the OS X client _allows_ this `disallow` setting. Much like compiling okular without DRM support in order to copy a sentence from a peer-reviewed journal, it seems that this is a fundamentally user unfriendly setting.

Answer (score 9):

Freewheeling off [Hans](/u/210476)' [answer](/a/260928/99609) —thanks!— I wanted to streamline the invocation a bit, bypassing Terminal and ending up with the AnyConnect icon in the macOS Status Menu. (I'm on Mojave 10.14.6.)

First, launch Terminal, then change to the AnyConnect application binary's directory:

```sh
$ cd "/Applications/Cisco/Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

Make a copy of the original binary:

```sh
$ sudo cp \
"Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" \
"Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.orig"
```

Finally, overwrite the initial file with a shell script, changing `VPN host` to your VPN hostname or address and `user` and `pa$$w0rd` to your credentials:

```sh
$ sudo cat > "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" <<'SCRIPT'
#!/bin/sh

# The AnyConnect vpn utility takes some options and commands or else runs
# interactively.
# Its help command shows that -s reads a script from STDIN and that connect
# takes a host as argument.
# Further, the connect command takes the username and password from STDIN; we
# will supply them from a heredoc with the -s option.

/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s \
connect "VPN host" <<'CREDENTIALS'
user
pa$$w0rd
CREDENTIALS

exec "$0.orig"  # invoke the original app
SCRIPT
```

Now, you should be able to run AnyConnect from Spotlight or Finder just as usual. First our script will connect and then hand off execution to the app binary so AnyConnect will appear on the desktop Status Menu.

Comment: Awesome man, Cisco Anny Connect UX is like shit.

Comment: future reference: use `sudo -i` when write permission denied

Answer (score 3):

Security can be bolstered by using Keychain Access to store the password.

```
security add-generic-password -s 'vpnpassword'  -a 'user' -w 'password' -T /usr/bin/security
```

Here is the adjusted version of [Christian's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/99609/christian-reinstate-monica-c) idea. Removing the internal heredoc quotes is required for parameter expansion to work.

```
sudo cat > "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" <<'SCRIPT'
#!/bin/sh

/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s \
connect "VPN host" <<CREDENTIALS
user
$(security find-generic-password -ws vpnpassword)
CREDENTIALS

exec "$0.orig"  # invoke the original app
SCRIPT
```